# Cannot rename database due to prepared transactions

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to rename a database using:

```
ALTER DATABASE xxx RENAME TO yyy
```

I got an error message saying there is another open session. I killed it using:

```
SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pg_stat_activity.pid)
FROM pg_stat_activity
WHERE pg_stat_activity.datname = 'xxx' AND pid <> pg_backend_pid();
```

However, I then got an error message saying there are 2 prepared transactions pending. I made sure  to kill all processes in the background with:

```
SELECT pg_cancel_backend(pid) FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE pid <> pg_backend_pid();
```

But still, I am not able to rename the database.

I then saw there is a view by postgres called **pg_prepared_xacts** that shows me the prepared transactions (shortened the gid for a better overview), and indeed, there are two of them:

```
transaction|gid           |prepared                     |owner|database|
-----------+--------------+-----------------------------+-----+--------+
5697779    |4871251_EAAAAC|2022-08-05 15:50:59.782 +0200|xxx  |xxx     |
5487701    |4871251_DAAAAA|2022-07-08 08:05:36.066 +0200|xxx  |xxx     |
```

According to the Postgres documentation on prepared transactions, I can execute a Rollback on the transaction id - which is what I did:

```
ROLLBACK PREPARED '5697779';
```

I made sure to execute the ROLLBACK with the same user, but it shows an error message saying that the transaction does not exist...

How can I get rid of it / kill it in order to be able to rename the database?

Thank you for reading and taking time to respond.

Comment: I think you need to use the `gid` value in the `ROLLBACK PREPARED`

Comment: @AdrianKlaver It worked, feel free to post your message as an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From here [Prepared transaction](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-prepare-transaction.html):

> transaction_id

> An arbitrary identifier that later identifies this transaction for COMMIT PREPARED or ROLLBACK PREPARED. The identifier must be written as a string literal, and must be less than 200 bytes long. It must not be the same as the identifier used for any currently prepared transaction.

and from here [Rollback prepared](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-rollback-prepared.html):

> transaction_id

> The transaction identifier of the transaction that is to be rolled back.

Lastly from here [pg_prepared_xacts](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-prepared-xacts.html):

> gid text

> Global transaction identifier that was assigned to the transaction

So to rollback the transaction you need the global identifier assigned in the `PREPARE TRANSACTION` as shown in the `gid` column in `pg_prepared_xacts`.